# Xcode rebuilds project when nothing has changed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

In the last few months we've noticed that Xcode seems to be rebuilding our project every time we 'Run', even if no files have changed.  How do I determine what is causing this to happen so that I can prevent it?

We did start using Swift in the last few months as well...not sure if it's related.

Also, one reason that the problem is so noticeable is because of some extra build phases that we have which execute shell scripts that take time.

Comment: Just an idea: Check if one of your source files has a modification timestamp in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's intention by Apple, or an Xcode bug. However, you can select ⌘⇧R (command+shift+R) to rerun without rebuilding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!